# Rails/Nginx: 403

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx, apache2, http-status-code-403

I'm getting a 403 error on my new rails testing page: removed.com:8080. I installed RVM as root, and everything seems to be running correctly (with my limited knowledge of Ubuntu...).

Here's what my log is reading:

```
2012/03/26 21:53:33 [error] 11698#0: *2 directory index of "/" is forbidden, client: 150.182.203.216, server: rails.pixelcraftwebdesign.com, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", host: "pixelcraftwebdesign.com:8080"
```

*What am I doing wrong?!* :( I've googled this for about 4 hours...

Comment: ALSO! This will read the app.../public dir if there is an `index.htm` located there...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're attempting to list directory and it appears that .htaccess/server is restricting this. Go to the actual controller/action as per your routes.rb implementation (e.g. pixelcraftwebdesign.com:8080/home/index if you have home_controller and it has index method inside)

Comment: Runing via nginx, so .htaccess shouldn't be an issue...and I'm not sure what you mean. My routes should be good. I followed this tutorial: http://railsapps.github.com/tutorial-rails-mongoid-devise.html

Comment: Check it out yourself...I get a proxy error there...gotta take one issue at a time. :/

Comment: http://pixelcraftwebdesign.com:8080/home/index
http://rails.pixelcraftwebdesign.com/home/index gives a proxy error

Comment: it says DNS fails to find rails.pixelcraftwebdesign.com:8080home - add "/" before home in the route

Comment: yeah, but that's a separate issue from my main question. However, where would I add "/"?

Comment: Just changed my proxy in apache config by adding "/" after the port number...check now. Now back to the issue at hand!

Answer (score 0):

Most likely you don't have the correct permissions set on your home or web directory.

Make sure that you have 755 permissions set throughout your path, to allow the non-privileged user that nginx is running as to traverse your directories and read your files.

Some Linux distros will automatically set restricted permissions on your home directory :
/home/user
As a security precaution to prevent other users from reading your files.

Comment: Just ran `sudo chmod 755 ergo` (ergo is my app dir). What else should I do? I feel like it isn't a permissions error...

Comment: Are running nginx and apache in a reverse proxy config on this server?

Comment: I am. See my update. Also see the links for an updated error. :)